# Is it a good idea to use quite long string keys for hash tables in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I've been thinking on possible simplest ways to implement a localization system to my scripts so their UI text can be easily translated to other languages and, among others, one way that pass through my mind is just use the original English text as hash keys for the table entries, so you only have to check if the key exists (not even needing to loop along them all) and that way return the matching key's value as translated text.

Well, that's more or less the theory... But the first thing I wonder is if couldn't be some caveat/s I'm not taking into account about using such kinda long "strings" (although I doubt in my case they passed 256 characters long or so) as table keys. I think my main worries would be about reliability and, to a lesser extent, any possible performance issues, but any other aspects you could consider worth to know about it would be welcomed.

The only thing I've found on this regard is the following discussion thread: [Max length of string keys in hash tables](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-04/msg00808.html), where they talk about possible collisions [HERE](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-04/msg00813.html), but it may not be a problem at all in my "some hundreds of characters as much" case. Though I'm not sure I totally understand all the exposed details and thus my question here...

Answer (score 3):

In terms of "reliability" or "maintainability", using the english source text will work just as well as coming up with other identifiers for localized strings; in both cases, you just have to make sure that the strings are equal, which I would argue *may* be slightly easier if you restrict yourself to Lua identifiers (e.g. you won't run into issues with blanks vs. spaces or the like where strings may visually appear equal but are different behind the scenes). Using the english text as identifier is often more convenient because it makes writing the translations trivial. Whenever you update a source string, you will have to make sure to update/remove the translations as well. For this purpose it might be a good idea to stick to a certain convention for translation strings in your sources, such as `T"..."` (where `T` is a function providing the translated string), which makes it easier to `grep` for translation strings to keep them in sync with translations and to have a "template" which basically would just be a table `["english"] = nil` with all translateable strings to be filled out for individual locales.

In terms of performance this is very unlikely to be an issue. Granted, this will require loading the English strings into memory, but these won't take up much; as long as you're not working in an embedded environment, this will be negligible. String comparison in Lua is **constant time** because Lua **interns all strings** as they are created (which means different string get different references, equal strings get equal references, which both means (1) the string isn't stored twice, (2) string comparison is reference comparison), so you don't need to worry about the cost of string comparison when Lua is doing the hash table lookup. Furthermore, I don't think longer strings will make hash collisions any more likely; and even if they did, I assume it would be mostly negligible.

**TL;DR:** Using the english source text as keys is totally fine both in terms of performance and maintainability.

Comment: Thank you very much too for the detailed answer! So I understand there would be no technical limitation I should worry about regarding strings length and that was the main reason for me to ask, although I've finally got much more than that. I'll have to think a bit more about your proposal regarding keep strings in sync because I'm not sure I totally get it, it seems to suggest some kind of strings update automation and that sounds great, but if it's going to complicate the simple function I had in mind I'm not sure that's something I'll be able to do, but I'll continue thinking about it...

Comment: Yes. I don't know the scale of your project; you can probably do the updating manually at this stage.

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea since the beginning anyway, just go updating the doubled strings manually... And regarding project scale, it wouldn't be too much trouble after all, given that the main tool (of which I'd be the only one in charge of its maintenance and main translations) won't count with more than a hundred of strings and the little scripts accompanying it are not supposed to be too much UI based. So, well, now I think I'll be (more) able to decide which solution is better in base of what I already have and everything exposed here... Thanks again for all the attention!

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially talking about a system that does the following:

1. You have a string X which needs translating into language Y.
2. You ask the translation DB to access language Y and get a translation for string X.
3. You receive the string Z which is the translation of string X in language Y.

This means that every language database must have a copy of every string X for which a string Z exists in that language. These are the keys in its hash table.

My question is ultimately this:

Where did string X *come from*?

That is going to be your biggest issue. Someone, somewhere, in some particular system, said "I need to display a string." That "a string" has a conceptual meaning, a purpose and function within your user interface. And in many cases, this "a string" is going to be hard-coded for that particular part of the interface. That is, what "a string" is is spelled out somewhere in your code or other UI-building stuff.

Your system effectively wants "a string" to be "string X". That is, the conceptual meaning of the string shall be the English translation of that string. Every language database now has the English translation of that string in addition to its own. But this text is also inside of your UI code/building stuff as "a string".

In short, you now have redundant information. And that means they can get out-of-sync.

If someone is looking at the UI code and sees that the English text is misspelled, they may change it. But that change will *not* be propagated into the text in every language database. So now, you have text in the UI that has no translation.

Every language maintainer must now fix their language DBs. But this work is not *meaningful* to them, because it's simply changing the keys. They still have to do it, but not because the translation is in any way damaged. It's just busywork to realign with something else.

This is why "a string" should probably *not* be the English version of the string. If you use an abstract representation of the string, once you set its value, you can choose never to change it. Even if it is misspelled, nobody will ever *see* the misspelling, because the English database will remap it.

Now you could have done the same thing in the above example, just changing the English DB to spell it correctly and leave the "a string" misspelled. But then... what's the point of using the English version at all? Just because a string could be an abstract idea of the string doesn't mean it must be inscrutable. Your "a string" could be something *near* the English version without having to be the literal English version.

In short, you can make "a string" English text without guaranteeing that it is the *exact* English text. Don't establish an idea that "a string" must be the literal English text that is displayed in the English translation. Allow it to be some English words that represent the string without *being* the string. And once you set it, it must remain *fixed*.

Basically, follow the rules of DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. The English translation displayed in the UI should exist in exactly and only one place: the English database.

Comment: Wow, I came looking for copper and I found gold... You definitely made me rethink about some points and now some aspects I saw as advantages has revealed to be disadvantages... e.g. I thought this way I could reuse some repetitive string translations, but yeah, what if during translation tasks I realize the UI forces me to use an abbreviation in certain part of UI but not in other? That will start complicating things and that's precisely what I wanted to avoid... Regarding the original string duplication, that's something I had kind of assumed anyway (MORE)

Comment: (CONT'D) because I like the idea of also having it at hand while translating, but it's true that base all the functioning on it can be a maintenance problem for the exposed reasons. Curiously, I already had a workable localization system based in string indexes not being the literal English text but I wanted to see if I could somehow simplify/improve it and now I think I'll surelly get stick to it, but it's nice to know it's going to be for good reasons. Well, thank you very much for taking the time of writing such an answer far beyond and expectations!

Comment: @Ramon0: Remember: the "string indices" can be text; that's fine. It's good if they can describe what the text means. But they shouldn't specifically be the literal English text that they represent.

Comment: Yeah, I get it! I mean, I think at first I was kind of blinded for the apparent advantages of not having to worry about write anything different from the original string, the simplicity of the needed function to make it work, and all... to the extent that I didn't think too much about the possible disadvantages. But now I'm conscious about all that and I think I can decide much more wisely what (not) to do thanks to you both :)